# Angular-cli test coverage all files

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-cli

I am running the following command to unit test and generate code code coverage report.

```
ng test --code-coverage
```

It is  writing code coverage report in coverage folder.

I need to see the coverage of the whole project and not just the file for which there are tests.

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'angular-cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-remap-istanbul'),
      require('angular-cli/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-sourcemap-loader')

    ],
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['angular-cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    remapIstanbulReporter: {
        reports: {
          html: 'coverage',
        lcovonly: './coverage/coverage.lcov'
      }
    },
    angularCli: {
      config: './angular-cli.json',
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'karma-remap-istanbul']
              : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    coverageReporter: {
      includeAllSources: true
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Comment: Have the same problem. Have you solve it?

Comment: @Vnuuk https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1735

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue and I found a simple workaround that does the trick for me without any big configuration.

1. In your app folder, create a file app.module.spec.ts
2. In this file add an import to your app module.

`import './app.module';`

That's it ;)

The point is, your app module is most likely the central part of your application which imports any other used files directly or indirectly. Now that you have created the spec file, everything that is included by your module should also be included in the test coverage report.

I am not 100% sure if this works with lazy loaded modules. If not, you can simply import those lazy loaded modules in your app.module.spec.ts as well, or create a spec file per module, where you import the module.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work in Angular 7.12 / NgRx. The test time out. :(

Comment: In my current project we use angular 7 (not 7.12 yet) and ngrx and the tests run fine. So either there is something in 7.12 which breaks this or you might have another issue with your code.

Comment: I don't know what Angular 7.12 is (7.1.2 perhaps?) but it works perfectly well with Angular 7.2.7.

Comment: Sorry, must be a typo. I meant Angular 7.2.10. It helps to know that this is working for others. Thanks.

Comment: I tried adding an untested component inside a nested module and the results did not change so this cant be working

Answer (score 10):

Here is the way to do this:

1. Add `client` section to your `karma.conf.js` like this:

   ```js
   plugins: [
       ...
   ],
   client: {
       codeCoverage: config.angularCli.codeCoverage
   },
   files: [
       ...
   ],
   ```
2. Change your `test.ts` to require files according to `codeCoverage` parameter:

   ```js
   let context; 

   if (__karma__.config.codeCoverage) {
       context = require.context('./app/', true, /\.ts/);
   } else {
       context = require.context('./app/', true, /\.spec\.ts/);
   }

   context.keys().map(context);
   ```

---

**UPDATE:**

Since Angular CLI `1.5.0` additional steps are required:

3. Next to `tsconfig.spec.json` add `tsconfig-cc.spec.json` file with the following content:

   ```js
   {
     "extends": "./tsconfig.spec.json",
     "include": [
       "**/*.ts"
     ]
   }
   ```
4. In your `angular-cli.json` add the following to `apps` array:

   ```js
   {
     "root": "src/",
     "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
     "test": "test.ts",
     "testTsconfig": "tsconfig-cc.spec.json"
   }
   ```
5. In your `karma.conf.js` add the following to `angularCli` section:

   ```js
   app: config.angularCli.codeCoverage ? '1' : '0'
   ```

   eventually it should look something like this:

   ```js
   angularCli: {
       environment: 'dev',
       app: config.angularCli.codeCoverage ? '1' : '0'
   },
   ```

---

So what's happening here?

Apparently they have fixed Angular compiler plugin and it takes the file globs from `tsconfig.spec.json` now. As long as we include only `**/*.spec.ts` in `tsconfig.spec.json` these are the only files that will be included in coverage.

The obvious solution is making `tsconfig.spec.json` include all the files (in addition to `require.context`). However, this will slow down all the tests even when running without coverage (which we don't want to).

One of the solutions is using the ability of `angular-cli` to work with multiple apps.
By adding another entry into `apps` array, we're adding another configuration for "another" (which is actually the same one) app.
We strip out all the irrelevant information in this config, leaving just the test configuration, and put another `tsconfig` which includes all the `ts` files.
Finally, we're telling `angular-cli` `karma` plugin to run the tests with the configuration of the second app (index `1`) in case it is running with code coverage and run with the configuration of the first app (index `0`) if it is running without code coverage.

*Important note:* in this configuration I assume you have only one application in `.angular-cli.json`. In case you have more you have to adjust indexes accordingly.

Comment: in Angular 6 the file `.angular-cli.json` was changed to `angular.json` and the structure is different. There's no `apps` array anymore, `projects` is the closest. Also there's no `angularCli` section in `karma.conf.js`

Comment: This is no longer a valid answer for David's reasons

Answer (score 1):

I've just created karma plugin, which adds all the files in the project to coverage statistic - https://github.com/kopach/karma-sabarivka-reporter.

To use it → install `npm install --save-dev karma-sabarivka-reporter`

And update `karma.conf.js` like this:

```
reporters: [
  // ...
  'sabarivka'
  // ...
],
coverageReporter: {
    include: 'src/**/!(*.spec|*.module|environment*).ts', // glob patter which  matchs all the files you want to be included into the coverage result
    exclude: 'src/main.ts',
    // ...
},
```

This solves issue without any other manipulation. Easy to add to existing projects as well as to new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [Tom van green](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49259776/4786536) solution, I came up with this (working perfectly on Angular 12).

```js
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('Global', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule]
    });
  });

  it('Extends coverage to all classes', () => {
    expect(true).toBeTrue();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) in ./src/test.ts set 
/ Then we find all the tests.

```
const context = require.context(‘./app/’, true, /\.ts/);
```

instead of standart
2) update src/tsconfig.spec.json with

```
“include”: [


 “**/*.ts”
```

3) in angular.json set

```
“test”: {
     “builder”: “@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma”,
     “options”: {
       “codeCoverage”: true,
       “main”: “src/test.ts”,
       “polyfills”: “src/polyfills.ts”,
       “tsConfig”: “src/tsconfig.spec.json”,
       “karmaConfig”: “src/karma.conf.js”,
       “styles”: [
         “src/styles.scss”
       ],
       “scripts”: [],
       “assets”: [
         “src/favicon.ico”,
         “src/assets”,
         “src/config”,
         “src/manifest.json”
       ]
     }
   }
```

I mean add this param “codeCoverage”: true

And for me it includes all files

I mean add this param “codeCoverage”: true

And for me it includes all files

Comment: this is not working for me at all. Some of my tests arent running and I get no code coverage report...

Answer (score -1):

karma.conf.js should be like this. No other configuration is required ng cli will take care of everything. stop the previous run `ng test` and run `ng test --code-coverage`.

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The problem is that by default only code that is required within `spec.ts` files gets checked for code coverage. Code without a corresponding spec file is not counted, so coverage stats are incorrectly inflated.

Answer (score -9):

Use below given command to check code coverage:

```
ng test -cc
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for. Angular-cli will only check code coverage for files that have a spec. OP is looking for a way to do all files regardless of whether they have a spec or not