# How can I add node_modules folder to Istanbul test coverage report?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, code-coverage, istanbul, karma-coverage

Within my org we have a few npm-like teams. My team creates a library of angular components, but we have had to develop inside of node_modules to keep our paths consistent when other teams pull in our code base.

To do so, I have had to update the `tsconfig.app.json`. And for our unit tests, I have had to update a few files:

**test.ts**

```
const nodeContext = require.context('../node_modules/uicomponents', true, /\.spec\.ts/);
// const  context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts/);

// context.keys().map(context);
nodeContext.keys().map(nodeContext);
```

**tsconfig.spec.json**

```
"include": [
  "**/*.d.ts",
  "../node_modules/uicomponents/**/*.ts"
]
```

With this, our unit tests run perfectly, but our Istanbul/karma code coverage isn't reporting for test files in node_modules.

**How can I tell Istanbul to include `node_modules/uicomponents`, and ideally, exclude `src/app`?**

I have attempted to makes similar changes as suggested [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280401/angular-cli-test-coverage-all-files), but I'm still not getting a report for my node_modules test files.

Comment: Why do you have to build in the `node_modules` folder? You can compile your output to say a `dist` folder and then set up your `tsconfig.json` to map your imports from your library (i.e. `import { Component } from 'uicomponents'`) by setting up the `paths` property so that it knows where to find the `uicomponents` path since it isn't in the `node_modules` folder like it would be for your consumers.

Comment: I don't disagree, but this is the project structure that I have inherited and we have dependencies on other internal "libraries" also in node_modules. However, tests have nothing to do with building. Basically what I'm looking for is: how I can point istanbul to report on folders outside of the src folder.